# Unable to Reference Pivot Table Sufficiently in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table, vlookup

[image]I have a Pivot Table with Participant names and 3 columns that associate with it. Of the 3 columns many are blank depending on the data presented.

I am referencing the pivot table in 2 ways and neither are using the getpivottable formula (doing this because I can not fill down the formula). The first is referencing a cell within the pivot table, adding the 3 columns that associate with the participant name (B5+C5+D5) and the other is using vlookup such as =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B9,Data!$A$3:$C$370,2,0),0).(I have iferror because when I filter the pivot table to one participant all the others vlookup formulas will show NA)

The issues I am trying to solve are

1. If I filter the Pivot table and one or two of the 3 columns that associate with the participant name are blank the pivot table will not display the blank columns and my (B5+C5+D5) formula with show incorrect results. This is fixed if I use the getpivottable function but I would like to be able to fill down or be able to do a bulk change since there are a lot of formulas so right now that does not seem plausible.
2. If I filter the Pivot table to one participant name the vlookup formulas referencing all the other particpant names will show 0 or NA if I remove Iferror. Am I able to filter the pivot table while having the vlookup formula see everything outside of the filter as well?

Many Thanks,

edit: Picture is of the Pivot Table (Filtered to one participant) up until the column that states USD. Further to the right is referencing the pivot table and converting currencies. As you can see the "GBP to CAD" and "Total in CAD" do not match the pivot table when filtered. When unfiltered it matches. Is a possible solution to copy the pivot Table data somewhere else and then reference that for the conversion?

Basically I need a solution for the data referencing the pivot table, showing either errors or incorrect results when filtered.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For your question 2, if you don't control by participant then you will get all the values...

Comment: @SolarMike How do I take away the control?

Comment: Please show a sample of the pivottable and the expected result.

Comment: Possible helpers may understand some parts of your questions (better) if you provide some screenshots.

Comment: Mate, you're better of having your formulas reference the source data table. Or as @Daghan suggested, use a duplicate pivot for formula referencing.

Comment: @Xlsx That may be the best solution if no other solutions are Viable I will look to that. However it is a lot of data that the pivot table condenses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Pivot Table shows only the items for which there is data. I generally do not recommend the use of absolute cell references to look into pivot tables.

**Question 1**

> To avoid blank data right-click on either a rows or columns type field
>   choose field settings->Layout & Print->Click 'Show items with no data'

Repeat the instructions above for each item with blank data fields.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/JNWyvHT.png]

**Question 2**

*Am I able to filter the pivot table while having the vlookup formula see everything outside of the filter as well?*

Well, no. But you have some options:

**Option 1:**
Duplicate the pivot and save the unfiltered pivot to a datasheet, reference to the pivot on the datasheet directly, this way - the lookups are unaffected by the filters you apply.

Note: remember to update all pivots when data changes (CTRL+ALT+F5)

**Option 2:** 
Assuming you are calculating something outside of the pivot, consider creating some calculated fields within the pivot

**Option 3:** Reference the source data of the pivot if you are not in need of aggregated data (counts, sum, average etc.)

Comment: Option 1 will work for the vlookup formula, I will see if that will work for the example I provided in the picture - Thanks I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: Hi I am issuing you the bonus Daghan. If I am unable to get it to work would you be able to continue helping? I will be trying to today or tomorrow. - Thanks

Comment: Sure, but it will be monday as im travelling this weekend